# Visual studio list/search for partitions

Tags: list, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, partition, disk-partitioning

I have partitioned my usb drive to look like a cd (partition A) and a normal thumb drive(partition B). I want the cd(A) to auto run a visual studio program that will look for the other partition on my thumb drive(B) and launch another visual studio program that i have made.

So it goes

Cd >autorun >visual studio app >search for other partition> launch other visual studio app.

This would be easy if i assigned drive letters to the drives but since im going to be using this on many different computers i cant do it every time.

So it comes down to this. Is there a way i can search for a second partition from visual studio and then launch another program on that partition?

Comment: Autorun is almost never enabled on modern OSes. Also, why not just place both programs on the same partition?

Comment: Auto run for cd's are. Thats why i have a nirmal thumb drive partition and a cd partition on my usb. So i can use the cd auto run to run a program from the usb partition. If i could i would just partition the whole drive as cdfs but i need read write capabilities to delete and stuff. I cant delete on the cd partition thats on there so i need the second partition which is a normal thumb drive partition.